# Get new list with conditional increment order of elements from list of lists

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, nested-lists

I have list of list of integers as shown below:

```
 flst = [[19],
 [21, 31],
 [22],
 [23],
 [9, 25],
 [26],
 [27, 29],
 [28],
 [27, 29],
 [2, 8, 30],
 [21, 31],
 [5, 11, 32],
 [33]]
```

I want to get the list of integers in increasing order as shown below:

```
out = [19, 21, 22, 23, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33]
```

I want to compare every list item with the item/s in next list and get item which is greater than the preceding item:

for ex:
In the list first item is [19] and next list items are [21,31]. Both elements are greater than [19] but [21] is near to [19], so it should be selected.

I'm learning python and tried the following code:

```
 for i in range(len(flst)-2):
    for j in flst[i+1]:
        if j in range(flst[j], flst[j+2]):
            print(j)
```

Went through many codes for incremental order in stackoverflow, but unable to find any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
flst[0]=flst[0][0]
for c in range(len(flst)-1):
    flst[c+1]=sorted([n for n in flst[c+1] if n>flst[c]],key=lambda x: x-flst[c])[0]
```

Output (in flst): `[19, 21, 22, 23, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33]`

Answer (score 1):

as close to one line as I could get

```
func = lambda x, t=[]: ([t.append(min([i for i in c if i > max([0]+t)])) for (index, c) in enumerate(x)], sorted(t))[1]

func(flst)
[19, 21, 23, 25, 26, 27, 29, 29, 30, 31, 31, 32, 33]
```

Comment: Output is not the same as the desired output